# Little issue with search for a certain string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search for rows that contain a certain string.
For that, I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT `1` as 'msgTime',
       `4` as 'shout'
FROM   log.shout_log' WHERE shout LIKE '".$name."' ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I'm getting `$name` from:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

My url:
./shout_log.php?name=Montz

But I encounter the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' WHERE shout LIKE 'Montz' ORDER BY 1 DESC' at line 1

Everything is to return a message that this name shouted.

```
$ms = $row['shout'];
echo '<span style="color:blue;">'.$ms.'</span>';
```

Whats wrong with my query?

EDIT:

```
$name = "%".$_GET['name']."%";
    $info = mysql_query("SELECT `1` as 'msgTime', `4` as 'shout' FROM log.shout_log WHERE 'shout' LIKE '$name'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo '<table><tr><th>Data</th><th>Menssagem</th></tr>'; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($info)){ 
        echo '<span style="color:blue;">'.htmlspecialchars($row->shout).'</span>'; 
    } 
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: quote before your WHERE statement

Comment: I must be blind, thank you, but still.. I get no returns.

Comment: Show the data in your table

Comment: You don't have any wildcard characters, so `shout LIKE 'Montz'` is the same as `shout = 'Montz'`. It performs an exact match.

Comment: But in my db the data is like this:

NAME: blablabla

I need to get the name so I can return blablabla

Comment: Don't put backticks around `1` and `4`. Backticks are for column names, not literal values. If those really are the column names, that's just perverse.

Comment: You absolutely should not use `$_GET['name']` directly. Imagine a person putting in an evil name like `"; drop table user;" --`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann That won't do anything because `mysql_query` doesn't allow you to execute multiple queries.

Comment: I edited it, now there no errors but no values returned

Comment: have you tried using % like Barmar said. $name = "%".$_GET['name']."%"; Then in your sql use WHERE shout LIKE '$name' ORDER BY 1 DESC

Comment: No values returned.. Edited again

Comment: my table: http://i.imgur.com/iu9uWss.png (I can't post images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave your column names aliases in  your query, so:

```
$ms = $row['4'];
```

should be

```
 $ms = $row['shout'];
```

or

```
 $ms = $row['msgTime'];
```

whatever you were looking for, I don't even know, your numerical column naming strategy is ridiculous

**EDIT**

Ok so change:

```
WHERE shout LIKE
```

to:

```
WHERE `4` LIKE
```

**EDIT2**

ok my bad do this:

```
$query = "SELECT `1` as 'msgTime', `4` as 'shout' FROM log.shout_log WHERE 'shout' LIKE '$name'";
echo $query;
$info = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Yes I know, its from a  game source that I can't really change. But using $ms = $row['shout']; gives me the error: Unknown column 'shout' in 'where clause'

Comment: edited again, now I get no errors, but no values either

Comment: If I use 4, `4` , shout or '4' I get no errors, but no values :|

Comment: SELECT `1` as 'msgTime', `4` as 'shout' FROM log.shout_log WHERE 'shout' LIKE '[GA]Montz', still no values ..

Comment: ok well you're missing the percent signs from the like clause, it should be `LIKE '%[GA]Montz%'` but you have `$name = "%".$_GET['name']."%";` So it should work. I don't know what went wrong but that's where you should be looking

Comment: Yes, I tried with the % too, but it didn't work, so I removed it and paste it here, sorry. But it still didn't work  SELECT `1` as 'msgTime', `4` as 'shout' FROM log.shout_log WHERE 'shout' LIKE '%[GA]Montz%'

Comment: try `var_dump($row);` after `while($row = mysql_fetch_object($info)){ ` to see if you're getting anything back at all, sorry changed it to `$row`

Comment: SELECT `1` as 'msgTime', `4` as 'shout' FROM log.shout_log WHERE '4' LIKE '%[GA]Montz%' still nothing xD. also tried to do mysql_fetch_array on the while and I didn't get anything

Comment: not 4 in single quotes!! should be 4 in backticks ` 4 ` (without spaces)

Comment: It finally worked, thank you, sorry for the stupid table names :D

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the comments, you had an extra '.

Regardless, I wanted to point out that what you are doing is extremely dangerous since it is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.

For example, if I say my name is:

```
  ';drop table `shout_log`; --
```

Then it will kill your database table.

Please see the following question [for proper code to avoid SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: I edited it and it still doesn't return anything, but thank you for that link

Comment: I believe that's because you intended to write something like: `WHERE shout LIKE 'NAME: ".$name."' since your text string starts with NAME:

Comment: 'Unknown column 'shout' in 'where clause' '

Comment: I don't know the names of the columns in your database.  Substitute `shout` with the correct name.  Before you had 'shout' in parentheses meaning it was comparing $name to the word 'shout'.  I doubt that's what you intended.